# While trying to make a Div scrollable, it is giving an error

Tags: jquery, user-interface, html, scroll

I am trying this since a long but failed. Please help me.

I am trying to make a div scrollable but when i am giving 
`$(divElement).scrollable({ vertical: true, circular: true });` , it giving me an error.

My divElement is vertical_corousel.Here is the stylesheet I am using.

```
.vertical_carousel {
    background: url(../images/btn_carousel_up.jpg) no-repeat top left;
    height:22px;
    width:290px;
    /*cursor:pointer;*/
    margin-bottom:35px; 
    position:relative;
}



.vertical_carousel .prev, .vertical_carousel .next  {
    height: 22px;
    width: 40px;
    cursor:pointer;
    float: left;
}

.vertical_carousel .prev {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.vertical_carousel .next {
    margin-left: 100px;
}
```

Please use this link to get some idea

http://jsfiddle.net/eCbXx/

thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not giving error but the statements after this line is not getting executed

Comment: I GOT THE PROBLEM, THEY HAVE USED SCROLLABLE PLUGIN AND IT IS NOT WORKING HERE. CAN ANYBODY LET ME KNOW HOW TO CONFIGURE IT.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do ([jfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Tpwpp/))?

Best,

Cynthia